# Web Test recorder does not allow me to record a test IE11 windows 7

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2013, web-testing

I am trying to record a Web Performance Test using the **Web Test Recorder 12.00** plugin that comes with VS 2013.

This is what I get when the toolbar opens:
[image]

As you can see the buttons are greyed out and disabled.

I have followed [this work around](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/16/using-internet-explorer-11-and-not-able-to-record-a-web-performance-test-successfully.aspx), but without any luck.

Are there any restrictions for this tool?

Is that a known issue?

Answer (score 8):

I have disabled the Web Test Recorder Helper Add-on and restarted IE, and enabled Add-on again. And it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm brand new to performance testing, and ran into the same problem using VS 2015, Win 7, IE11. The culprit in my case was an IE11 add-on called "Office Document Cache Handler". Microsoft was the one that created the add-on (which I find rather frustrating), but hopefully this helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Been around for years. Unfortunately, Microsoft has no sure fire method to resolve it.

I am currently having this issue and would really like to find a supported solution, as I will not be shelling out the big bucks for 2013 Ultimate with this issue stopping me from using it for web load testing.

Issues with this have been under discussion on msdn since at least 2007: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mtaute/archive/2007/11/09/diagnosing-and-fixing-web-test-recorder-bar-issues.aspx

#### 3rd party edit

The link above contains different "fixes" depending on the OS and the VS version. The version 2013 was not mentioned. But to include at least some information the following quotes are extracts from Michael Taute (MSFT) post:

```
VSTS 2005: Vista: 
Recorder bar displays, but the controls are disabled.

Fix:  Webtest recording using VS 2005 on Vista only works when running in
elevated mode.  [When launching VS 2005, right click the icon and choose to
run as administrator]
```

or

```
VSTS 2005, 2008: Windows 2003/Vista: 
Recorder bar comes up, but the controls are disabled.

Fix: the web test recorder bar does not work with IE enhanced security 
enabled.  (VSTS 2008 will actually display an error message telling you 
this)  IE enhanced security can be removed from within the Control 
panel / Add Remove Programs / Windows Setup
```

or

```
VSTS 2005, 2008, 2010 Beta 1: Windows 7: 
When launching the recorder, the recorder bar does not appear

Fix:  The Windows 7 security model is slightly different than previous
versions of windows. (go figure :)   
To get the recorder to show up, you’ll have to run Visual Studio 
in elevated mode.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Your answer would be improved if you included a link/reference to MS knowing about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've got TWO addons:

- Microsoft Web Test Recorder 12.0 Helper (Publisher = "Microsoft Corporation")
- Web Test Recorder 12.0 (Publisher = "Not Available")

Both of them should be enabled, otherwise recorder toolbar is grayed out or not displayed at all. I'm running Windows 10 and VS 2013 update 5.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding 'WebAndLoadTestProject' to existing solution, Start with new solution as given in below steps.

1. Open Visual studio in 'Run As Administration' mode
2. Create new project -> Test -> add 'Web performance And Load Test Project'.[WebAndLoadTestProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQvkm.png)
3. This opens IE browser with record button enabled state.