# Web Test recorder is disabled in IE11, Win7

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2015, web-testing

I am trying to record a web performance test using the web test recorder 14 plugin in the explorer 11. I have the exact same problem as described in this [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642397/web-test-recorder-does-not-allow-me-to-record-a-test-ie11-windows-7) post, which unfortunately does not solve the problem for me. I did the following tasks:

1. Looked in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mtaute/archive/2007/11/09/diagnosing-and-fixing-web-test-recorder-bar-issues.aspx) which does not contain my case
2. Made sure that "Web Test Recorder 14.0" and "Microsoft Web Test Recorder 14.0 Helper" Add-on is enabled
3. Made sure that "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode" in the internet options is not checked (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/16/using-internet-explorer-11-and-not-able-to-record-a-web-performance-test-successfully.aspx))
4. Even deleted some registry keys as suggested on the page I mention the line above.
5. Restarted the computer.

Any idea how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue after enabling Microsoft Web Recorder Helper